# How to print text when a user types a specific word?

Tags: python

When a user types in a specific word, I want to print out a set of words, kinda like a search engine.
e,g I type in cookie and it prints out cookies are tasty
if i type in wthwergebqeg print out that word did not return any results
I'm new to this kind of python, I have made other kinds of small programmes and want to get into this.

Comment: show what you have tried. people here would like to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dictionary for this

```
replies = {'cookies' : 'cookies are tasty',
           'car': 'cars are fast',
           'beer': 'beer is good'}
```

Then you could use the dictionary as follows

```
>>> query = input('Enter a word : ')
Enter a word : beer

>>> replies.get(query)
'beer is good'
```

If you try to `.get()` a word that is not in the dictionary, `None` will be returned.

Answer (score -1):

You can make dictionary and check if there is an word there. Check this:

```
dictionary  = {'cookies' : 'cookies are tasty',
       'word': 'word is made of letters',
       'cheetah': 'cheetah is fast',
       'uncle': 'my uncle is ben',
       'example': 'this is an example'}

input = raw_input("Enter word:")
if dictionary.get(input) != None:
   print replies.get(input)
else:
   print "That word did not return any results"
```

You can use lists too, but that would make larger code, since you need more if/else statements... Here is an example:

```
list = [cookies, word, cheetah]
input = raw_input("Enter word:")
if input in list:
   if input == "cookies":
      print "Cookies are tasty"
   if input == "word":
      print "Word is made of letters"
   if input == "cheetah":
      print "Cheetah is fast"
else:
   print "That word did not return any results"
```

I hope this helpes you to solve ur problem.